# Attaching arbitrary information to an SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game with Sprite Kit in which I generate many instances of an `SKSpriteNode`. When I detect a collision between two sprites, I can easily get a lot of data about the colliding sprites (position, rotation, scale, etc.).

My question: Is there a way to embed arbitrary information, like a string or integer, into the sprite? Say I wanted to timestamp each sprite with the time it was generated, and then display that when it collides with something.

`UIButton` come to mind, where you can define `button.tag`, and use that information later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SKNode](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData) has a `userData` dictionary where you can store data.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass SKSPriteNode and add properties. This will allow you to attach whatever information you would like to your sprite while retaining the built in SKSpriteNode functionality.